# SQL Server - get all databases and files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I know about getting the database names by doing the following:

```
select * 
from master..sysdatabases 
order by Name
```

What I want to be able to do is return all the files related to each database on the server. To get the list of files per database I have to do something similar to the following:

```
use [database]

select * 
from sysfiles
```

Unfortunately I need the use prefix as `sysfiles` only pulls from the database I'm using.

Ideally I want to be able to wrap this into a view that can be called and hooked into zabbix via an odbc database monitoring item.

Let's say I have 3 database:

```
DB1
DB2
DB3
```

I want a view that will show

```
Database Name    FileName
--------------------------------
DB1              c:\mnt\db1.mdf
DB1              c:\mnt\db1.ldf
DB2              c:\mnt\db2.mdf
DB2              c:\mnt\db2.ldf
DB3              d:\mnt\db3.mdf
DB3              d:\mnt\db3.ldf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query it using the `sys.databases` and `sys.master_files` views:

```
SELECT
    db.name,
    FileName = mf.name,
    PhysicalFileName = mf.physical_name,
    Type = mf.type_desc 
FROM sys.databases db
INNER JOIN sys.master_files mf
    ON mf.database_id = db.database_id
WHERE db.name NOT IN('msdb', 'master', 'tempdb', 'model')
ORDER BY db.name
```

Comment: This is awesome!  Question though, what security level is required?  If I run in my sandbox where I have full SA access I get everything, but on our dev environment which is more locked down I get nothing so I'm guessing it's a permissions issue related to the account I'm using.

Comment: confirmed the issue is with sys.master_files table I have access to sys.databases.

Comment: It's "teach a man to fish" day here at SO. The documentation for sys.master files (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx) says "The minimum permissions that are required to see the corresponding row are CREATE DATABASE, ALTER ANY DATABASE, or VIEW ANY DEFINITION."